# Creating a JSON post request with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, http-headers, request

I am experimenting with the Rapaport Technet API, and want to hit an endpoint which expects the following JSON:

```
{
    "request": {
        "header": {
            "username": "my_username",
            "password": "my_password"
        },
        "body": {}
    }
}
```

Code:

```
url = 'https://technet.rapaport.com:449/HTTP/JSON/Prices/GetPriceChanges.aspx'
headers = {'username': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password'}
r = requests.post(url, headers)
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "header": {
            "error_code": 1001,
            "error_message": "Invalid format"
        },
        "body": {}
    }
}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [example](https://technet.rapaport.com/Info/RapLink/SampleCode/JSON_CodeSample.aspx) from Rapaport Technet API docs, that whole JSON is sent to be as data in the POST request. So simply do the same as given [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in Requests docs.

```
json_data = {
    "request": {
        "header": {
            "username": "my_username",
            "password": "my_password"
        },
        "body": {}
    }
}
r = requests.post(url, json=json_data)
```

Comment: I tried moving the header to the data like so- {'request': {'body': {}, 'header': {'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'}}}. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3549700 - Oh my bad. Try using `json.dumps` and then send the data. I've edited my answer.  Have a look.

Comment: Tried this as well and the same thing. I also copied the dict I'm working with from their example, so I doubt the problem is there.

Comment: @user3549700 - Okay. Try `json=json_data`.

Comment: same result. Do you know if the json request paramemter serializes the dict? anyway i tried both json = json_data and json = json.dumps(json_data) and errors were had...

Comment: @user3549700 - Is it giving the same error as you posted in the question?